# Cannot complete login to a 3rd party site using stack exchange openid provider

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

I'm trying to login to a forum with my stack exchange openid and I receive this upon successfully entering my uname/pass:

> Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier
>   (http://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.

What's causing this, and how can I get around it?

Comment: What site was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked the next time i tried it on the following day, so it must have been a fluke in the other site i was trying to log into.