# Cannot login to a 3rd party site using delegated ID

Tags: bug, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I am using OpenID delegation, set up on my homepage to delegate to stackexchange. Previously I used MyOpenID as the backend, but as it will be closed down in February I have switched to SE as the backend.

However on [magiclantern.fm](http://magiclantern.fm/forum) the delegated ID does not work, as I'm getting the following error:

```
Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (http://sztupy.hu/) is not owned by the logged in user.
```

If I switch back to MyOpenID backend everything works fine, and I can log in, but that won't be an option after February.

Note: I know about [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125419/cannot-complete-login-to-a-3rd-party-site-using-stack-exchange-openid-provider), but that's not about delegation, and doesn't have any answers.